# How to replace letters with a corresponding number

Tags: python, python-2.7

My question is: if I have a string like “lake" and I wanted it to be replaced with a set of numbers like "1,2,3,4", how will I be able to do it?
To be more clear I want each letter to have a corresponding number. Hope I'm clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a ton of ways: enumeration, dictionary, dual arrays, etc. Depends on how you want to do it

Comment: No, you're not clear. Why does "lake" correspond to "1,2,3,4"? You need to explain that, and you should show us your own attempt at writing code for this.

Comment: Are you trying to ask about the algorithm where each new letter in the string is assigned a letter starting from 1?  so `abac` -> `1213` or `abccb` -> `12332` ...  using `lake` is a really bad example if that is what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little bit generic, but let me show you a little example where  you transform your input into "something" and you can recover your source string from that "something":

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 .,?!"

def crypt(c, key):
    return ord(c)-key

def decrypt(c, key):
    return chr(c+key)

my_string = "lake"
key = 97
dst = [crypt(c,key) for c in my_string]
src = [decrypt(c,key) for c in dst]
print dst
print ''.join(src)
```

There is no general rule which answers your question of `I want each letter to have a corresponding number`, for the sake of simplicity, just use a relevant [bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) function to transform/untransform your strings and you're done.

Of course, I'd recommend you not sticking to this simple answer of mine and reading about this topic in some of the zillion of specialized books out there :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: @MercuriusAltar You're welcome, best way to thanks somebody here in SO is accepting questions or upvoting them ;)